# Terraform aws: [WARN] retryable error: dial tcp: lookup self.public_ip on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

**Issue:**

Hello All,

Thanks for your time. So I am new to Terraform and in general devops.
I feel I am doing something wrong under the provisioner connection block.
I'm trying to create an ansible master and slave configuration using terraform. For my master to be able to talk with the slaves, need the ssh public keys of the master node to be available in all slaves in .ssh/authorized, for that I'm trying to ssh and pass on the master public keys while creating the slave.
For some reason I am not able to ssh into the slave while creation I tried all I could have imagined and went through lots of forums. I'm sure I maybe doing something wrong here.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards.

**Terraform Version**

```
Terraform v0.13.0
```

**Terraform Configuration Files**

```
variable "region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}

variable "type" {
  default = "t2.micro"  
}

variable "ec2LinuxAmi" {
  type = map(string)
  default = {
    us-east-1 = "ami-0bcc094591f354be2"
  }  
}

variable "keyname" {
  default = "terraformKeys"  
}

variable "privateKeyPath" {
  description = "Path to private key"
  default = "/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa"
}

variable "awsKey" {
  default = "terraformKeys.pem"
}

variable "user_names" {
  description = "Create IAM users with these names"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["ansibleMaster"]
}


provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  shared_credentials_file = "/home/userName/.aws/credentials"
  profile = "default"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "port_22_ingress_globally_accessible" {
    name = "port_22_ingress_globally_accessible"

    ingress { 
        from_port = 22    
        to_port = 22
        protocol = "tcp"
        cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
}

resource "aws_instance" "linux"{
  count = length(var.user_names)
  ami = lookup(var.ec2LinuxAmi, var.region)
  instance_type = var.type
  security_groups = [ "port_22_ingress_globally_accessible" ]
  key_name = var.keyname

  tags = {
    Name = var.user_names[count.index]
}

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "foo"
    destination = "/tmp/foo"
  }
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "ubuntu"
      host = "self.public_ip"
      port = 22
      private_key = "${file("/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
  }
}
```

**Debug Output**

```
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [WARN] Provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" produced an unexpected new value for aws_instance.linux[0], but we are tolerating it because it is using the legacy plugin SDK.
The following problems may be the cause of any confusing errors from downstream operations:
- .disable_api_termination: was null, but now cty.False
- .ebs_optimized: was null, but now cty.False
- .hibernation: was null, but now cty.False
- .monitoring: was null, but now cty.False
- .iam_instance_profile: was null, but now cty.StringVal("")
- .credit_specification: block count changed from 0 to 1
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [TRACE] eval: *terraform.EvalMaybeTainted
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [TRACE] eval: *terraform.EvalWriteState
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: recording 0 dependencies for aws_instance.linux[0]
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [TRACE] EvalWriteState: writing current state object for aws_instance.linux[0]
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [TRACE] eval: *terraform.EvalApplyProvisioners
2020/08/30 19:10:30 [TRACE] EvalApplyProvisioners: provisioning aws_instance.linux[0] with "file"
aws_instance.linux[0]: Provisioning with 'file'...
2020-08-30T19:10:30.228-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: file-provisioner (internal) 2020/08/30 19:10:30 using private key for authentication
2020-08-30T19:10:30.229-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: file-provisioner (internal) 2020/08/30 19:10:30 [DEBUG] Connecting to self.public_ip:22 for SSH
2020-08-30T19:10:30.248-0400 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform: file-provisioner (internal) 2020/08/30 19:10:30 [ERROR] connection error: dial tcp: lookup self.public_ip on 127.0.0.53:53: no such host
```

**The debug ends with:**

```
"Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed
(ubuntu@18.204.3.15:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to
authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods
remain".
```

Answer (score 0):

Your host will be just a string "self.public_ip":

```
host = "self.public_ip"
```

It should be:

```
host = self.public_ip
```

Also `connection` should be inside `provisioner` block:

```
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "foo"
    destination = "/tmp/foo"

    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      user = "ubuntu"
      host = self.public_ip
      port = 22
      private_key = "${file("/home/userName/.ssh/id_rsa")}"
    }
  }
```

Lastly, `aws_key_pair` resource is not being created. But maybe it was excluded from the question.

Comment: Sorry for coming out as a complete noob. I tried your suggestion, it still gives me the retryable error. And I should probably add, (will add now) that the after about 5 mins the debug ends with 
"Error: timeout - last error: SSH authentication failed (ubuntu@18.204.3.15:22): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain". 
Also, I did create an aws pem key through the AWS web console, do I need to re create it using terraform?

Comment: The failure to connect to `18.204.3.15:22` seems like a separate problem than the name resolution failure you were originally asking about here, because it shows what is presumably now the correct public IP address for your EC2 instance. For that reason, I'd recommend opening a new question on Stack Overflow that includes the full  configuration you have after incorporating Marcin's advice and the full error output you're now seeing, because the solution to this new problem is likely to be distinct from the first one you encountered.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks, will do that.